# How to avoid duplicate rows in my Scenario SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my sql query and result. I got the result what I expect. But it's adding additional rows in my result.

My query

```
Declare @store1001 varchar(10)='1001'
Declare @storeAll varchar(10)='StoreAll'

select ID,StoreID,TotalQtyParent into #tempQuantity
From
(
    select ID,@store1001 StoreID,Sum([TotalQtyParent]) TotalQtyParent
    FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelationQty]
    where StoreID='1001' and TotalQtyParent is not null
    group by ID

    Union

    select ID,@storeAll StoreID,sum([TotalQtyParent]) TotalQtyParent
    FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelationQty]
    where StoreID<>'1001' and TotalQtyParent is not null 
    group by ID
) totalquantity
```

**Above query result**
[image: Result for above query]

**OutPut Query**

```
  select TotalQty.ID, item.ItemLookupCode,item.Description,
    (
        case when TotalQty.StoreID = '1001' then TotalQty.TotalQtyParent
        else 0 end
    ) WHS,
    (
        case when TotalQty1.StoreID = 'StoreAll' then TotalQty1.TotalQtyParent
        else 0 end
    ) Store

FROM
#tempQuantity TotalQty
INNER JOIN #tempQuantity TotalQty1 on TotalQty.ID=TotalQty1.ID
LEFT JOIN HQMatajer.dbo.Item item on item.id=TotalQty.ID


order by WHS desc,Store desc
```

Final Output

[image: Final output]

> you can see the **every second record of ID and the value of Store is Zero(0)**. I don't want to show that row.
>
> Please don't suggest me to add the condition in where clause where store <> 0. It's showing result because of my first query result,There every ID is two times are available. 
>   Thanks
>
> **UPDATED**
>   I removed some columns from my output query to understanding purpose

Comment: It's not clear what do you want because your clearly got two **StoreID** for each **ID** in **[HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelationQty]**. You must decide how to aggregate/circunavigate this. For example you can try aggregate (SUM) by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `PIVOT` ?

```
SELECT 
     ID, 
     [1001] AS WHS, 
     [StoreAll] AS Store
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       ID, StoreID, TotalQtyParent
    FROM #tempQuantity
) AS TotalQty
PIVOT
(
    SUM(TotalQtyParent)
    FOR StoreID IN ([1001], [StoreAll])
) AS PivotTable;
```

And then just use joins...

Comment: Yes, Exactly this is what I am expecting. Thanks.